# Redirect domain/url by .htaccess

Tags: html, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have one Wordpress website that I want to redirect the entire domain and all pages associated with it to another website but after 2 seconds.

Maybe with `.htaaccess` or something.

Like-
when anyone go to `www.domainA.com` he will redirect in- `www.domainB.com` after 2 second or instantly

when anyone go to `www.domainA.com/apps` he will redirect in- www.domainB.com/apps after 2 second or instantly

when anyone go to `www.domainA.com/2013/05/avery-on-tortorella-bret-hart-apology-cm-punk-update/` he will redirect in- `www.domainB.com/2013/05/avery-on-tortorella-bret-hart-apology-cm-punk-update/` after 2 second or instantly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On `www.domainA.com` place this code in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /temp.php?uri=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Then in `temp.php` page place this code to **redirect to domainB after 2 seconds**:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;URL=http://www.domainB.com<?php echo $_GET['uri'];?>">
</head>
```

Comment: Why you redirect user to some temp html with 2 sec. redirect? Why not instant redir.?

Comment: Instant is also possible but usually 2 sec delay is introduced to show some flash message like `"site has moved to new address"`.

Comment: yes, but my view is that users need your page ASAP, info about redirection is delay for them. better is show some header on new page, that user was redirected from old domain. but with full content of page..

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Source: http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/migrate-domains/